# Lottie Player with Next.js

Tags: next.js, lottie

I have Next.js project where I use lottie-player for a few animated icons. However, I'm getting the following error everythime I run the project. Once the error is closed, the application runs with no problem.

NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "lottie-player" has already been used with this registry.
What am I doing wrong?

I have installed the Lottie player and I'm importing lottie player using useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    import("@lottiefiles/lottie-player");
  });
```

and subsequently use the icons as such:

```
    <><script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js" async>. </script>
    <lottie-player src="https://assets5.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_YIBaBZH9fj.json" background="transparent" speed="0.5" style={{ "width": "200px", "height": "150px" }} loop autoplay></lottie-player>
    </>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import Lottie from "lottie-react";
import animationData from "@/public/lottie/error-404.json";
export default function Custom404() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col w-full justify-center items-center">
      <Lottie
        animationData={animationData}
        className="flex justify-center items-center"
        loop={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This works perfectly for me.

I am using `npm i lottie-react`

Answer (score 0):

I did it something like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!window?.customElements.get(`lottie-player`)) {
      import(`@lottiefiles/lottie-player`);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).